# stored queries in a variable for debugging dont show up

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

in my PHP MySQL class, each time I run a query I'm storing it inside a public var, so that I can print all queries at the end of a script to debug how many i'm doing on each page. As well as ensure they're what I want them to be doing.

My problem, is that not all of the queries seem to be showing up. I think it's due to how I'm using my class.

Here's a snippet from the class:

```
class db_mysql extends PDO
{   
    protected static $instance;

    public $stmt;

    // the query counter
    public $counter = 0;

    // store all the queries for debugging
    public $debug_queries = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // allows LIMIT placeholders
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
        ];
        parent::__construct("mysql:host=".DB['DB_HOST_NAME'].";dbname=".DB['DB_DATABASE'],DB['DB_USER_NAME'],DB['DB_PASSWORD'], $options);
    }

    // a classical static method to make it universally available
    public static function instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    // the most basic query
    public function run($sql, $data = NULL)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
            $this->stmt->execute($data);
            $this->debug_queries .= '<pre>' . $this->replaced_query($sql, $data) . '</pre>';
            return $this;
        }
        catch (PDOException $error)
        {
            $trace = $error->getTrace();
            error_log('SQL ERROR ' . $error->getMessage());
            die('SQL Error');
        }
    }
```

So then inside any other class, I can do this:

```
class test
{
    private $dbl;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbl = db_mysql::instance();
        $this->dbl->run("some update query");
    }
```

My problem, is that it appears any queries done inside class "test" don't get added to the $debug_queries?

Comment: How are you trying to output the debug lines at the end of your code? Could you add that bit to your question?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it looks like the assignment in the sub class `test` ... is spawning a new db_mysql object. So anything done in it, is not being added to the more global db_mysql object you use in other ways. I could be wrong, I'm still hazy with `private` vs `protected` =p yes, even after 15 years of php lol.

Comment: Turns out it was because of the static method when calling it in another class. Setting $debug_queries to static and adjusting how the run function adds to it fixed it.

Comment: Where are you calling the "run" function from? Are you even calling it at all?

Comment: Yes I am calling it @JesseSchokker this was an example, i've edited it to include an example of how run would then be called (i've since solved it anyway and added my answer)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for pointing that out. Glad you were able to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was because when I'm accessing it as static from another class (like "test"), it doesn't add it to the non-static var.

Changing

```
public $debug_queries = '';
```

to

```
public static $debug_queries = '';
```

Along with adjusting this:

```
$this->debug_queries .= '<pre>' . $this->replaced_query($sql, $data) . '</pre>';
```

To this:

```
self::$debug_queries .= '<pre>' . $this->replaced_query($sql, $data) . '</pre>';
```

Has solved it and they all now show up no matter how it's called.

Comment: Nice to know! I've always either stuck with one way (static or not), and have not mixed, mainly for this reason... gets confusing ;)